# iOS delegation does not work, cannot fix it (code inside): sending data from UITableView to UITextField in another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegation

I searched extensively for delegation tutorials, but could not get it to work. Here is the story and the code.
DetailViewController has a UITextField and a UIButton. When you press the button you get to another PricelistViewController with a simple sectioned table. Tapping a row in that table should return the text from the row's title to the first view and insert it into the text field. But it doesn't. Here is the code:

**PricelistViewController.h** (the second view):

```
@class PricelistViewController;

@protocol PricelistViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
//- (void)theSaveButtonOnThePriceListWasTapped:(PricelistViewController *)controller didUpdateValue:(NSString *)value;
- (void)theSaveButtonOnThePriceListWasTapped:(NSString *)value;
@end



@interface PricelistViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <PricelistViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * listOfSections;

@end
```

**PricelistViewController.m**

```
@synthesize delegate;


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfSections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"ProductSections"];
    NSString *selectedProduct = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.delegate theSaveButtonOnThePriceListWasTapped:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", selectedProduct]];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

This is the code in **DetailViewController.h** (the first view with a text field and the button):

```
#import "PricelistViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, PricelistViewControllerDelegate>
```

**DetailViewController.m** (this I how I am trying to change the text in the field):

```
- (void)theSaveButtonOnThePriceListWasTapped:(NSString *)value
{
    NSLog(@"Text, sent here: %@", value);
    NSLog(@"Text was sent here.");
    self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = value;

}
```

**detailDescriptionLabel** is the UITextField for the text to display.

Can somebody check the code and help? I work on this matter two days with no luck!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly why are you forward referencing (@class) your class in the header file of the PriceListViewController? This isn't needed.

Secondly are you using ARC, if you are your array property should be of type nonatomic, strong. If you're not your delegate property should be nonatomic, assign. You seem to be mixing your terminology

Also where and how are you initialising your array?

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your feedback! Without class declaration the compiler returns error `Expected a type` and Yes, I'm using ARC. I changed the property of array to strong - no luck. I initialize my array in ViewDidLoad of PriceListViewController 
`listOfSections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Comment: `NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfSections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"ProductSections"];
    NSString * selectedProduct = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
In the PricelistViewController.m I changed the way I call the method (added If statement):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfSections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"ProductSections"];
    NSString *selectedProduct = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (delegatePrice && [delegatePrice respondsToSelector:@selector(theSaveButtonOnThePriceListWasTapped:didUpdateValue:)])
    {
        [delegatePrice theSaveButtonOnThePriceListWasTapped:self didUpdateValue:selectedProduct];
    }
```

AND THE MOST IMPORTANT: I refused to use the Storyboard and instead made a old good .xib file for my PricelistViewController view and it worked right away!